# Wildfly9 domain mode cluster deployment with High Availablity

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly, high-availability, wildfly-9

We have a web application which works fine on Wildfly9 standalone mode. Currently its on a single server. We want to add one more server to avoid high traffic and downtime issue.

I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/WildFly+9+Cluster+Howto?_sscc=t . But this deployment is referring domain mode.

**Can we use clustering and load balancing using standalone mode?**

If answer to above question is no then we are thinking of deploying application to domain mode on two different server and also add load balancer.

I tried to deploy application war in domain mode but our application refer many configuration files which are outside war.

1. Is there any way using which  I can provide path to config file/directory?
2. Do I need to put these config files in war itself?
3. Do I need to configure application somehow to look for these files from WILDFLY_HOME?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use clustering and load balancing using standalone mode?

Yes, you can deploy you application in both standalone and domain mode with load balancing and clustering.

> I tried to deploy application war in domain mode but our application refer many configuration files which are outside war.

There are multiple ways to provide configuration files

1. You can put config files in the war itself.
2. You can put config files under some location and set values in Configuration: System Properties.
3. You can also put these file under some location and mount that location to another server. So that both servers refer same configuration and modifying config at one location will reflect change for both servers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use standalone with high availabilty.
There is this document describing this mode: 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Load+Balanced+HA+Standalone+Cluster+-+Howto

However, I only found this document for Wildfly 8, but afaik it should work on wildfly 9 as well.

Comment: I referred that link but this doc explains that you deploy application on two servers and add a load balancer. Whereas I am looking for something like load balancer + high-availability in which if one server (master) crashes then end users will be able to access application using another server (slave).  Session should get copied from master to slave , so that end users should not loose his/her work.

Comment: did you try it? it should work because in ha mode Wildfly can use Infinispan to replicate session date. see also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/High+Availability+Guide